# MUI responsive Tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tabs

Is it possible to make MUI `Tabs` to be responsive?

What I have:

[image: what I have]

What I want to achieve:

[image: what I want to achieve]

Answer (score 3):

You can set [`flexWrap: 'wrap'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) in the tab container component which is a flexbox:

```
<Tabs
  // disable the tab indicator because it doesn't work well with wrapped container
  TabIndicatorProps={{ sx: { display: 'none' } }}
  sx={{
    '& .MuiTabs-flexContainer': {
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },
  }}
  {...}
>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 0):

Building on @NearHuscarl's answer, here's a Tailwindcss example (assuming it is [already configured to work with MUI](https://mui.com/base-ui/guides/working-with-tailwind-css/)) that wraps only for smaller screens.

```
<Tabs
  TabIndicatorProps={{ className: "hidden sm:block" }}
  classes={{
    flexContainer: "flex-wrap sm:flex-nowrap",
  }}
  {...}
>
```

I also prefer [using the API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tabs/#css) whenever possible, hence the `flexContainer` object on the `classes` property.